# WoW Weakauras Custom Tricker

Tags: lua, world-of-warcraft

I am trying to get a trigger that will show with the sunfire debuff has less time then my nature's grace buff.  the lua calls seem to be pulling the correct number, but it is constantly returning true?

```
function ()
    _,_,_,_,_,_,sundur= UnitDebuff("target","Sunfire","player");
    _,_,_,_,_,_,NGDur= UnitAura("player","Nature's Grace");
    if sundur and NGDur  then
        if sundur<NGDur+2 then
            return true
        else
            return false
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: What makes you think that sundur should ever be >= NGDur + 2?

Comment: You forgot to mention what are the values of nundur and NGDur. ALso, as a rule of thumb you can just do `return (a < b)` instead of `if (a < b) then return true else return false`.

Comment: Thank you for the responses.  sundur should be >NGDur when sunfire is cast after the NGDur Proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue i found was that the ad don was allowing the declared variables to be saved globally which was causing it not to be updated properly even as i changed them.  I also had to change one part of code, removing the "" around player only on the uniteDebuff "caster" filter.

```
local _,_,_,_,_,_,sundur= UnitDebuff("target","Sunfire",player);
```